# failed: Access denied on meteor collection

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app has the insecure and autopublish removed and accounts-password added.
It uses `Accounts.createUser({username: someName, password: somePwrd});`  which can be verified on the mongo prompt.

I am trying to `Tasks1.insert(params);` and getting access denied

I don't know why it get Access denied for update and insert on the browser console. Please tell me why and how to fix it? Thanks

```
//both.js
Tasks1 = new Mongo.Collection('tasks1');
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//server.js
Meteor.publish('tasks1', function(){
  return Tasks1.find({userId: this.userId});
});

Meteor.methods({
  logMeIn: function(credentials) {
    var idPin = credentials[0] + credentials[1];
    Accounts.createUser({username: idPin, password: credentials[1]});
  }
});

Meteor.users.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
   console.log(userId);
   //var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
  return true;
}
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

//client.js
Template.login.events({
   'click #logMe': function() {
   var credentials = [$('#id').val(), $('#pin').val()];
   Meteor.call('logMeIn', credentials, function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
      console.log('logged in!');
    }
  });
 }
});
Template.footer.events({
  'click button': function () {
    if ( this.text === "SUBMIT" ) {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       var params = {};
       params[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
       Tasks1.insert(params);  //<<<<<<----------------------
    }
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Are the files also in the appropriate directories (server/client etc.)? And are you actually storing the user's password in the database in cleartext as part of the username?

Comment: Yes to both questions :)

Comment: What is the path of the `server.js` file relative to the project root?

Comment: appName/server/server.js

Comment: Then I don't see why something like that should happen. Probably another side-effect not mentioned in the posted code. Can you create a minimal reproducible example and post the error you are getting? In addition, why are you creating a user every time someone submits the form, and why are you storing the password in cleartext?

Comment: Please see updated code and the explanation in the questions. I need the password to log in to a web site to verify the user, this app is a proxy to a site which requires login.

Comment: You allow inserts to `Meteor.users` (which is bad) but your error stems from attempting to insert to `Tasks1`. Therefore, you should allow inserts to `Tasks1` instead of `users` (you should probably still verify that the client is allowed to do the insert in your `allow` code, or better yet, use a method for it).

Comment: Thank you. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**
Since you have edited your question and added that `Tasks1.insert(params);` is getting access denied message,  you should add `allow` rules on `Tasks` collection and not `Meteor.users` collection.

```
Tasks.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
           return true;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
           return true;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
           return true;
    }
});
```

If `Accounts.createUser` is working without `allow` rules on `Meteor.users` then please remove them as it might allow users to insert/delete others from client itself.

**End of update.**

Since you removed `insecure`, you need to add `allow/deny` rules for inserting, updating or deleting files from a collection.

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
           //Normally I would check if (this.userId) to see if the method is called by logged in user or guest
           //you can also add some checks here like user role based check etc.,
           return true;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
           //similar checks like insert
           return true;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
           //similar checks like insert
           return true;
    }
});
```

Check the [API documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) for more details.

Comment: You should insert a fetch entry inside the Tasks.allow. You can see the API documentation attached for more info.

Comment: Shorter form:


```Tasks.allow({
    insert: (userId, doc) => true,
    update: (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) => true,
    remove: (userId, doc) => true,
 });```

Answer (score 0):

Defining your Meteor.methods like this will define it for both server and client. This means the you will be trying to create a user TWICE, once on the server (the one that works) and another time on the client. The client does not have the right to insert user documents so you receive this error.

There are two options for you:

1: Define the method on the server only by surrounding it by `if(Meteor.isServer)` or putting it in a folder named "server"

2: leave it as is, it will not cause harm but keep showing the error in console.

I am sure there is a 3rd and maybe 4th solution, but those are the two I'd use.

Comment: The method IS defined inside server.js, Did you mean the collection?

Comment: That would mean you did not tell us all... I see you updated the question and that you got your answer so I won't update mine.